# How do I link my SwiftKey on Windows 10 to the account I have on an Android phone

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've been using SwiftKey on my Android phone and I want to try it out on Windows 10.

SwiftKey learns as you type. I want to transfer what it has learned from my phone to my computer, is this possible and how?

Comment: It is not possible to run an Android application directly on Windows. [SwiftKey Keyboard for Android](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/swiftkey?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot_1%3aprimaryr2) only runs on Android.  [Swiftkey](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/10/windows-10-tip-swiftkey/) is a feature of the current version of Windows and is already enabled.

Comment: I want to link the cloudy part. SwiftKey learns as you type. I want to transfer what it has learnt from my phone use to that of my computer

Comment: You cannot run Android applications directly on Windows.  The feature you describe   does not exist in the Swiftkey functionality within Windows 10 1809+

Comment: I think people are misunderstanding the question, and OP misunderstands the role SwiftKey plays in the Windows experience, though the answers below are accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been using SwiftKey on my Android phone and I want to try it out on Windows 10.

Swiftkey functionality was added in the `Windows 10 version 1809`.

Source: [Windows 10 Tip: SwiftKey](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/10/windows-10-tip-swiftkey/)

> I want to transfer what it has learned from my phone to my computer, is this possible and how?

What you want is not currently not possible.  The feature you describe, does not exist, in the Windows 10 1809+ Swiftkey functionality.

> I want to link the cloudy part.  I want to transfer what it has learnt from my phone use to that of my computer

The cloud synchronization feature you describe only exists on the iOS and Android Swiftkey applications.  The Windows 10 1809+ Swiftkey feature cannot be linked to those applications.

[SwiftKey: Privacy Questions and your Data](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201454592-SwiftKey-Privacy-Questions-and-your-Data) only applies to the Android Swiftkey application.  It does not apply to the native Swiftkey functionality within Windows 10.  **In fact, all the documentation on the Swiftkey website only applies to the iOS or Android application.**

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication that is possible.

See https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201454592-SwiftKey-Privacy-Questions-and-your-Data and https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/community/topics as Microsoft has not made that publicly visible. You will need to ask them.

If and when you get your data from Microsoft, then you would need to consult [Windows 10 Touch Support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-touch) regarding how you could add that data to the Windows variant of Swiftkey.

Comment: [SwiftKey: Privacy Questions and your Data](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201454592-SwiftKey-Privacy-Questions-and-your-Data) only applies to the Android Swiftkey application.  It does not apply to the native Swiftkey functionality within Windows 10.  **In fact, all the documentation on the Swiftkey website only applies to the iOS or Android application.**

Comment: @Ranhound _I want to transfer what it has learned from my phone_ is what the OP wrote; first step, therefore, is to try to get data collected by the Android app.

Comment: I understand what the author is attempting to do, now that they explained what they are attempting to do, but Windows 10 1809 cannot use that information.

Comment: @Ranhound Source? Perhaps checking with https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-touch may find a different answer.

Comment: Your asking for my source for which statement?  The website clearly indicates it’s only for iOS and Android.  If Windows supported what the author wanted it would be documented.